Why does Grafana dashboard sometimes show only 1 of 2 exporter UP?
We are using JMX_Exporter for Cassandra 3.10 version. In Grafana Dashboard, sometimes we see Exporter UP goes down to 1 vs regular 2 and Node Status shows node down count ( It doesn't tell which node on GUI)
When this happens, I login to Cassandra and do nodetool status and all is fine. There are no issues reported in system.log as well.
Cassandra background process doesn't show that it went down since timestamp is old.
So what could be causing issue here ?
I have no knowledge on JMX_Exporter so don't know where to check for issues.
Can someone explain rules sections in yml file ?
cat /opt/jmx_exporter/jmx_exporter_cassandra.yml 
---
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: true
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(Connection|Streaming), scope=(\S*), name=(\S*)><>(Count|Value)
    name: cassandra_$1_$3
    labels:
      address: "$2"
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(ColumnFamily), name=(RangeLatency)><>(Mean)
    name: cassandra_$1_$2_$3
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.net<type=(FailureDetector)><>(DownEndpointCount)
    name: cassandra_$1_$2
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(Keyspace), keyspace=(\S*), name=(\S*)><>(Count|Mean|95thPercentile)
    name: cassandra_$1_$3_$4
    labels:
      "$1": "$2"
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(Table), keyspace=(\S*), scope=(\S*), name=(\S*)><>(Count|Mean|95thPercentile)
    name: cassandra_$1_$4_$5
    labels:
      "keyspace": "$2"
      "table": "$3"
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(ClientRequest), scope=(\S*), name=(\S*)><>(Count|Mean|95thPercentile)
    name: cassandra_$1_$3_$4
    labels:
      "type": "$2"
  - pattern: org.apache.cassandra.metrics<type=(\S*)(?:, ((?!scope)\S*)=(\S*))?(?:, scope=(\S*))?,
      name=(\S*)><>(Count|Value)
    name: cassandra_$1_$5
    labels:
      "$1": "$4"
      "$2": "$3"

Any idea where to look for issue which jmx_exporter is reporting for cassandra ?

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!
